# Page anchor with mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to set up page anchors on a website that uses mod_rewrite (Apache2 running on Ubuntu Server 9.04).

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^information.php/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ information.php?display=$1  [NC,NE]
```

If I was using regular URL's the query would look something like this: **http://mydomain/information.php?display=faq#cost**

I'm hoping to get something like this:
**http://mydomain/information/faq/cost**

Is this possible?  My understanding is that modrewrite ignores page anchors, and that the  browser deals with it? I'm guessing that I can somehow use mod_rewrite to include the anchor information with the request, but I haven't been able to find anything documenting this and have been trying unsuccessfully to write it myself for hours.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if you want the **resulting** URL to have an anchor, then yes, it's possible. Just don't forget that in Apache configs, # marks the start of a comment.

If what you want is like this - user enters

```
http://example.com/page/anchor
```

and gets redirected to

```
http://example.com/?p=page#anchor
```

- you would need to use 301 Redirect, or something like that, so it wouldn't be transparent to the user.

Conclusion: While it is possible to write such a redirect rule, it can't be done entirely server-side. So I think you could point `/information/faq` to `/information.php?display=faq` and then use URLs such as:

```
http://example.com/information/faq#foo
```

which are almost what you want, plus they don't mess up caching.

(Whoa, it's midnight already?)

Comment: +1, Good point, I misread the question and thought it was the other way around.

Comment: Hmm, I kind of misread the question too - while this redirection is possible, it won't be transparent to the user, as it can't be done server-side, only using HTTP redirects.