# htaccess mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble with url rewriting. I have the following rule working fine:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?/([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?theme=$1&pg=$2 [L]
```

which displays the url as follows:

```
domain.com/theme/pg
```

What i need is for the the url to rewrite to `domain.com/theme#pg` I thought the below would work, but it doesn't:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?#([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?theme=$1&pg=$2 [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the url you want to change from, and the url you want to change it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#` in the URL is the client-side thing - you should not get that on the server at all. You can rewrite **to** the URL containing an anchor, as given e.g. here:

- [Page anchor with mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941721/page-anchor-with-mod-rewrite)
- [mod_rewrite with anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686075/mod-rewrite-with-anchor-link)

but not **from** the URL containing a `#` - that would not get to the server at all.

Comment: I _think_ Aninemity is trying to convert it to that.

Comment: @GoldenNewby Yeah, what he says in English and what the last `RewriteRule` says in Apacheconfigian (is that how we should call the Apache configuration language?) is contradictory. I assumed `RewriteRule` was correct - theres's a 50% chance I'm right :) and the other 50% are covered by the links I added - so we should all be set :)

Comment: okay, so that's why my poor attempt didn't work. What i'm trying to do is have the rewrite rule change `domain.com/theme#pg` to `domain.com/page.php?theme=theme&pg=pg` sorry if i wasn't clear

Comment: Sorry, can't do that - take a look at this: http://blog.logeek.fr/2007/12/31/how-to-debug-rewrite-rules-with-apache, then after you configure as above try some URL requests from your browser and look what you get in the log file. Only what you get is something you can work off of. If you don't get the `#`, you cannot work with `#`. And since it's a client-only thing, you will not get it under normal circumstances (i.e. if you are using standard browsers). Testing yourself is best for learning, though :)